# How to replace <span style="font-weight: bold;">foo</span> by <strong>foo</strong> using PHP and regex?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string like this:

```
<span style="font-weight: bold;">Foo</span>
```

I want to use PHP to make it

```
<strong>Foo</strong>
```

…without affecting other `span`s.

How can I do this?

Comment: Use a dom parser instead of regex.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$text='<span style="font-weight: bold;">Foo</span>';
$text=preg_replace( '/<span style="font-weight: bold;">(.*?)<\/span>/', '<strong>$1</strong>',$text);
```

**Note**: only work for your example.

Comment: @anon Wait until you hit a `span style="font-weight:bold;"` (notice the lack of space between : and bold) or `span style="color:red; font-weight: bold;"` or any other perfectly valid html.

Comment: @Amarghosh thanks for the pointer about removing spaces, I was wondering why my text wasn't being bolded